# Headphone on Ubuntu 15.10 stopped working

Tags: sound, alsa, headphones, soundcard

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad w541, and a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.10. At the beginning the headphone was working ok, but after a couple of restarting it stopped working out of a sudden, although the built in speakers work fine.

Via alsamixer I see that I have two sound cards (one of them not showing headphone support), however even switching between them does not solve the problem.

[Here](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=3a056596700e4d9baa2678a25c012379e8b5c834) is the my uploaded alsa info.

Any help is appreciated.